# Вывести все нечетные числа из строки

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вывести все нечетные числа из строки. 
Пример кода, который при запуске зависает:

```
function gol () {
  var numb = prompt('enter the numbers');
  var arr = numb.split(' ');
  arr.push(0);
  var ar = [];
  for(i = 0; i != arr || i == arr; i++){
   var a = arr / 2;
   a = a.toString();
   if(a.search(',') === true){
     ar.push(a);
   }
  }
}

console.log(gol());
```

Comment: Ну это не особо осмысленный набор символов

Comment: Что по вашему мнению происходит тут: `i != arr || i == arr`?

Answer (score 3):

> вывести все нечетные числа из строки.

```js
let input = '12 10 7 13 6 5 4 11'; // Строка ввода, у вас prompt
let numbers = input.split(' ');    // Делим по пробелам на числа

console.log(getOdds(numbers).join(', '));
console.log(getOddsArrFunc(numbers).join(', '));
console.log(getOddsLoopIf(numbers).join(', '));


// Возможные реализации:  
// Array.prototype.filter
function getOdds(nums) {
  return nums.filter(function(num) {
    return num % 2 === 1;
  });
}
// То же, со стрелочной функцией
function getOddsArrFunc(nums) {
  return nums.filter(num => num % 2 === 1);
}

// Вручную в цикле
function getOddsLoopIf(nums) {
  const res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    if (nums[i] % 2 !== 0) res.push(nums[i]);
  }
  return res;
}
```

[Стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
[Фильтрация массива](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: `let odds = numbers.filter(num => num % 2);`  - можно еще так

Comment: @Node_pro, явное лучше неявного

Comment: возможно, но тогда лучше писать в старом стандарте. Ведь парень привел пример именно старого вариант)

Comment: Не все знают как работают стрелочные функции и их особенности)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var s = prompt("Введите строку с числами", "1 14 0 16, gshgfsd 777, -67,-76 8")
console.log((s.match(/-?\d*[13579](?!\d)/g) || []).join(", "))
```